# Immediate default api call done when selecting list - MEAN.JS

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack, meanjs

Instead of the basic CRUD module `articles` that is given, I have a similar one called `friends`. A `friend` is simply another `user` but is separate from the `user` module. I'm trying to make it so when a user selects to see the list of friends, they see **THEIR OWN** list of friends and not all of the ones stored in the `friends` collection in mongo. The structure of a `friend` in the mongo collection is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587b9e16d1bdf314181b354e"),
    "user" : ObjectId("5867c5e92fa4e91008788f80"),
    "added" : ISODate("2017-01-15T16:06:46.975Z"),
    "friend" : {
        "firstName" : "b",
        "lastName" : "b",
        "email" : "b@b.com",
        "profileImageURL" : "modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png",
        "roles" : [
               "user"
        ],
        "created" : "2017-01-11T17:28:19.849Z",
        "__v" : 0,
        "username" : "bbbbbb",
        "provider" : "local",
        "displayName" : "b b",
        "_id" : "58766b337f091f842addfd5a"
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

So the `user` field is the user which this `friend` is assigned to and the `friend` object is the actual friend.

I got the api call working easily enough by just adding another route which takes the user as a parameter:

> /api/**:userId**/friends/:friendId
>
> /api/**:userId**/friends

I've realised that *(and this is something that is default in MEAN.JS)*, in the client, if a user selects to see the list of friends, the call is immediately made to see **ALL** *(`/api/friends`)* friends in the collection in mongo.

I've looked all through the client but cannot see where this call is made!

What I want to do is find where this call is made and change it so that it includes the `:userId` as a param so only getting that users friends.

As it looks to me, as soon as you hit the template to view friends, the controller **should** make a `ngResource` query to the `FriendsService` to get the friends of a specific user:

```
function FriendsService($resource) {
    return $resource('api/:userId/friends/:friendId', {
        userId: '@user',
        friendId: '@_id'
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
}
```

...but obviously this is not the case.

**EDIT:**

I am happy that the `$stateProvider` is setup in the config of the friends module client side:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('friends', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/friends',
        template: '<ui-view/>'
    })
    .state('friends.list', {
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'modules/friends/client/views/list-friends.client.view.html',
        controller: 'FriendsListController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Friends List'
        }
    });
```

So when I hit the url `/friends`, what should happen as there is no controller or template associated with it?

However, in `friends.client.config.js`, the menu service is:

```
// Add the dropdown list item
menuService.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'friends', {
    title: 'List Friends',
    state: 'friends.list'
});
```

So my understanding is that when the sub-menu option to list friends in the UI is clicked, it uses that state which maps to the `FriendsListContoller`.

```
function FriendsListController(FriendsService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.friends = FriendsService.query();
}
```

So will query the `ngResource` of the `FriendsService`. The `FriendsService`:

```
function FriendsService($resource) {
    return $resource('api/:userId/friends/:friendId', {
        userId: '@user',
        friendId: '@_id'
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
}
```

So it looks like to me that when a user selects to see the list of friends, `/api/:userId/friends/:friendId` should be called.

The point is that I can see in my console that when selecting to view the list of friends, the call `/api/friends` is being made instead which gets **all** friends in the collection in mongo no matter who they are assigned to:

[image]

The call is clearly being made from the client somewhere but cannot find where.

3 questions:

1. Is my logic correct? In the sense that when a user selects to view the list of friends, the service is queried?
2. In the service, the params `userId` and `friendId` are set to `@user` *(which I set)* or `@_id` *(which was already there)*. My presumption was that these are the fields in the collection in mongo, is that right? Is there anyway I can debug the values that are passed into this call?
3. Where is the call '/api/friends` being made? As, logically in my head, I cannot find where it is being called in the client *(probably because I do not know enough of the MEAN.JS structure yet)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was relatively simple and I feel stupid for not thinking of this before.
MEAN.JS has an `Authentication` factory which can return the current user within the session *(`Authentication.user`)*
Just by using `Authentication.user._id` as the parameter for the `userId` in the REST call, I was able to do it. Here's my new `FriendsService`:

```
function FriendsService($resource, Authentication) {
    return $resource('api/:userId/friends/:friendId', {
        userId: Authentication.user._id,
        friendId: '@_id'
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you haven't passed the userId to the FriendsService, that's the reason when you execute `vm.friends = FriendsService.query();` query, the `/api/friends` url is triggered. You need to change the FriendsService to get the userId as input

You can write your factory like this

```
app.factory('FriendsService', function ($resource) {
return $resource('/:entity/:id/:action/:friendId', {id: '@id',friendId: '@friendId'}, {
    firendsList: {method: 'PUT', params: {entity: 'api',action:'friends'}}, // this calls the api/userId/friends api in PUT method you can use friendId here too for understanding i seperated the service. 
    fetchFriend:{method:'GET',params:{entity:'api',action:'friends'}}  // this calls the api/userId/friends/friendId in GET method
});
```

**Note:** You can make the `entity` ,`action` static as `api`, `friends respectively. Or can keep it configurable and use it for other methods too.

Now in your controller you can write

```
function FriendsListController(FriendsService) {

FriendsService.firendsList({'id': 'userId'}, function (response) {
            alert('Edited successfully');
            console.log(response)
        }, function (error) {
            if (error)
                alert(error)
        })

FriendsService.fetchFriend({'id': 'userId',friendId:'friendId'}, function (response) {
            alert('Friend Fetched successfully');
            console.log(response)
        }, function (error) {
            if (error)
                alert(error)
        })
}
```

1. Is my logic correct? In the sense that when a user selects to view the list of friends, the service is queried?

**Answer:** When a user selects to view the list of friends he has the `friendsList` service should be called.

2. In the service, the params userId and friendId are set to @user (which I set) or @_id (which was already there). My presumption was that these are the fields in the collection in mongo, is that right? Is there anyway I can debug the values that are passed into this call?

**Answer:** The `userId` and `friendId` is not really the fields in the mongodb collections, these are the resource variables used to call the service API's, The `userId`, `friendId` should be passed while you call the service. If these parameters are not passed the resource will take it as blank and call the `/api/friends` API since the `userId` and `friendId` is not defined.

3. Where is the call `/api/friends` being made? As, logically in my head, I cannot find where it is being called in the client (probably because I do not know enough of the MEAN.JS structure yet)

**Answer:** The answer is in the second question itself, if you do not pass the values for `userId`, angular service will omit the `userId` key in the API url which basically restructures as `/api/friends`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I gave this the bounty as you provided insight and answered all the questions I had. I have not accepted the answer as (even though I'm sure it'll work), it's not the way I have gone about it. See my answer for the way I accomplished it

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing that validation mainly in server side.

But first things first: taking into account that your friends api is similar in structure to the articles example api, once the requests are made, you should check which route endpoints are defined server side, mainly in the routes.js file in `/modules/friends/server/routes` and at the same time compare which controllers will handle the server side logic, which should be located in `/modules/friends/server/controllers`.

Now if you take a closer look there's a line in the routes file:

```
// Finish by binding the article middleware
app.param('articleId', articles.articleByID);
```

That's the starting point to solve your problem, you should bind the `userId` and `friendId` something like this:

```
app.param('userId', friends.userByID);
app.param('friendId', friends.friendByID);
```

So that in the server controllers you can access both directly via `req.userId` and `req.friendId`.

This should be the way to go and then in the controller for the `GET /api/:userId/friends`, you have to add the needed logic so that mongoose will query only the friends for that particular user and return them.

However if your Friends API is not in a separate module and is just an addition to the already defined User module, then you can make the adjustments to the User module similarly.

Comment: The starting section of that answer I have already completed. The section I am struggling on is where you mention: *"you have to add the needed logic..."*. This is where I struggle as, as far as I can see, on requesting the list of friends, the call `/api/:userId/friends` **should** be made in the friends service client side but `/api/friends` is the call being made instead. I will update my question and provide the output in my console